# I installed Hadoop on Ubuntu. If I run Hadoop commnds, I get "Unable to load native-hadoop library"

Tags: hadoop

When I run a Hadoop command, I get following error:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ hadoop checknative -a
15/12/24 14:01:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Native library checking:
hadoop:  false 
zlib:    false 
snappy:  false 
lz4:     false 
bzip2:   false 
openssl: false 
15/12/24 14:01:47 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to download source code and compile it for native libraries as described [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2a2to6lBN14&list=PLf0swTFhTI8pFYbcZA4bNWCjetRKVubPH&index=16)

It covers downloading the hadoop source code, set up maven, compile using maven for native libraries, copy to relevant directories.